# Best practice for production migration of TypeORM

Tags: node.js, typescript, migration, database-migration, typeorm

We use bamboo for CI and on the last step we call `npm prune --production` for clean devDependencies. TypeScript and ts-node is also dev dependencies.

Also we use TypeORM as ORM for out project. We are gonna use typeorm cli for auto migrations, applying and reverting it.
But we have a problem. TypeORM use ts-node for running cli but on production server we already have an image without dev dependencies.

Can anyone suggest best practice for typeorm migration in production? We don't want to deploy on production service ts-node and typescript, it's not good idea for us. It's look like very bad practice. Should we run migrations like one of CI step?

Also we think to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/db-migrate but prefer to use existed utils of our orm.

Comment: Running migration as a CI step seems dangerous to me. Why not run it from your computer? I think DB migration can't be fully automated.

Comment: Run from my personal computer is unacceptable because i have no credentials on my machine. Image get it from secret store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found a solution. We just compile a migration files to out dist folder and run typeorm cli commands without `--require ts-node/register`. It's work good for us.

Comment: So how do you run migrations in local ? and are your migrations automated with the deployments or you run migrations manually om server